# Calculating a trimmed mean at scale

Tags: elasticsearch, statistics, mean

I currently have a dataset that has many datapoints (on the order of billions) in Elasticsearch.  And I do statistics on those documents in ways that Elasticsearch provides (mean, median, percentiles, etc.)

However I now have need of a [Trimmed Mean](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trimmed_mean.asp) calculation.  In short this is when you order your data, and take off x% from both sides of your data (high and low) and calculate a mean on the remaining data points.  Ex the, the 5% trimmed mean of income would be eliminating those in the bottom 5% of income and those in the top 5% and doing a mean on the remaining income values

It's intended to be a measure of central tendency that reduces the impact of major outliers.

However from what I can see Elasticsearch doesn't support this and I can't find many things that do.  Even things like percentiles are hard to do at scale but Elasticsearch has algorithms that do some estimation (I think they're based on data sketches but I'm not completely sure there).

I could re-create this effect by querying my data for two percentiles (`x` percentile and `100-x` percentile), then do a third query that filters out those data points and does a mean.  That works, but now I'm doing three relatively long queries and ideally would like to minimize that back and forth with my dataset.

I said I'm using Elasticsearch and that's preferable in terms of a solution but open to any suggestions really

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'd be possible to do it in one go but here's my 2-step take on it.

First figure out the trim limits using a `percentiles` aggregation.

```
GET billion_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "boundaries": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "price",
        "percents": [
          5,
          95
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### **It's important to note, though, that with billions of values, percentile aggregations will [probably be approximate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation-approximation) and non-deterministic (yielding different results for the same query).**

---

The above query computes:

```
{
 ...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1558776,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "boundaries" : {
      "values" : {
        "5.0" : 1121.4101013907416,
        "95.0" : 1148582.9150790304
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Plugging these into a set of filtered extended_stats aggregations:

```
GET billion_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "standard_mean": {                 <--- for comparison of non-trimmed
      "extended_stats": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    },
    "pipelined_mean": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "price": {
            "gt": 1121,                <--- filter by % transformed to real vals
            "lt": 1148582
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "trimmed_mean": {              <--- calculate stats after having filtered
          "extended_stats": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yields

```
{
 ...
  "aggregations" : {
    "standard_mean" : {
      "count" : 1558390,
      "min" : 0.0,
      "max" : 8.888888888E9,
      "avg" : 368803.9027932674,                  <--- standard mean
      "sum" : 5.74740314074E11,
      "sum_of_squares" : 8.645745157058162E19,
      "variance" : 5.534268385940522E13,
      "std_deviation" : 7439266.352228909,
      "std_deviation_bounds" : {
        "upper" : 1.5247336607251085E7,
        "lower" : -1.450972880166455E7
      }
    },
    "pipelined_mean" : {
      "doc_count" : 1401944,
      "trimmed_mean" : {
        "count" : 1401944,
        "min" : 1123.0,
        "max" : 1148500.0,
        "avg" : 246760.4101305045,                <--- trimmed mean, understandably lower
        "sum" : 3.4594427642E11,
        "sum_of_squares" : 1.6918684996958976E17,
        "variance" : 5.978947692482006E10,
        "std_deviation" : 244518.86823887448,
        "std_deviation_bounds" : {
          "upper" : 735798.1466082535,
          "lower" : -242277.32634724447
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can either use `stats` or `extended_stats` depending on how much info you actually need.